# Different Eden of the East series?

Tags: eden-of-the-east

So about 6-8 months ago I watched Eden of the east on Netflix and I really enjoyed it. It felt really original and I was totally hooked. I soon after watched the movies.

So today on "Source Fed nerd - Anime Club" they reviewed the anime and one of the hosts (Meg Turney) said something about that Eden of the East had different series.

I've watched:

- Eden of the East (11 episodes)(Higashi no Eden)
- Eden of the East the Movie I: The King of Eden (Higashi no Eden Gekijoban I: The King of Eden)
- Eden of the East: Paradise Lost (Higashi no Eden Gekijôban II: Paradise Lost)

So the question is, what different Eden of the East, Seasons / Series / Movies are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's basically all of it - the 11-episode TV series, and then the two movies. There's also a recap movie for the TV series called [*Air Communication*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6927/Higashi_no_Eden_Soushuuhen%3a_Air_Communication), but there's no sense in watching it if you already watched the TV series.

In general, when you have questions about what anime exist for a given franchise, a good approach is to search for one of the anime on [AniDB](http://anidb.net) (e.g. [AniDB's page for Eden of the East](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=6238)), and look at the "relation graph" for that anime ([here's the one for Eden of the East](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=rel&aid=6238)). This shows all anime that are related in some way or another to the anime you were looking at. The relation graphs get kind of messy for huge universes like Gundam ([see graph](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=rel&aid=715)), but for most franchises, the relation graphs are quite useful.

Comment: Thanks so much, not just for the answer regarding my question but AniDB is new to me, look amazing! Good Answer!

Comment: +1 for sharing the site which also lists it resources which makes up for the fact it does not list the distributors

Comment: I would say that *Air Communication* is still worth watching even if you've watched the TV series, because it has audio commentary from the Eden club members that clarifies a lot of details about the events of the first series, and you get to learn a bit more about the Eden club members themselves.